# Laravel login system

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, logout

I'm doing an app using Laravel, and I'm doing a login system.
In login I don't have any problem, but in logout the browser gets an error

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
```

My login function

```
public function postSignin() {
    if (Auth::attempt(array('email'=>Input::get('email'), 'password'=>Input::get('password')))) {
        return Redirect::to('users/dashboard')->with('message', 'You are now logged in!');
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('users/login')
            ->with('message', 'Your username/password combination was incorrect')
            ->withInput();
    }
}
```

My logout function

```
public function getLogout() {
    Auth::logout();
    return Redirect::to('users/login')->with('message', 'Your are now logged out!');
}
```

If I remove the line `Auth::logout();` the page is redirected but I can't use the `Auth::check()` to verify the if the user is logged in.

After having the error `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.` if I refresh the page the redirect is done properly.

Any clue what the problem is?

**Edited:**

The error is just that

[image]

Comment: Can you post the specific error?

Comment: @lozadaOmr just edited with the image of the error.

Comment: Although just looking at your code, I can't seem to find any error. I'll just share how I did something similar basically `$credentials = array('username' => Input::get('username'),'password' => Input::get('password'));` Then do `Auth::attempt($credentials);`

Honestly, not sure if that would make a difference

Comment: Turn debug on (in `app/config/app.php`) to see a more useful error message

Comment: per default logging is enabled in laravel. you should find more details about the error in `app/storage/logs/laravel.log`.

Comment: First go to  `app/config/app.php` and set:

`'debug' => true,`

Now you can see error details

Comment: Thanks for the debug tip, I'm new at laravel, and I didn't know about that. 
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Laravel version > 4.1.25 you may be missing the remember_token field on the users table.

see: http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade#upgrade-4.1.26

Laravel requires "nullable remember_token of VARCHAR(100), TEXT, or equivalent to your users table."

Answer (score 0):

i hope to be helpful giving you this link to a package with build-in authentication signup and admin panel with permission handling.
Fully customizable: https://github.com/intrip/laravel-authentication-acl